# dynamically adding/removing a div to html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to dynamically create  a `div` element with `id="xyz"`. Now before creating this, I want to remove any other `div` with `id ="xyz"` if it exists. How can i do it?

```
var msgContainer = document.createElement('div');
msgContainer.setAttribute('id', 'xyz');  //set id
msgContainer.setAttribute('class', 'content done'); // i want to add a class to it. it this correct?

var msg2 = document.createTextNode(msg);
msgContainer.appendChild(msg2);
document.body.appendChild(msgContainer);
}
```

How can i remove all divs with `id =xyz` if they exist before executing above code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Removing:

```
var div = document.getElementById('xyz');
if (div) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

Or if you don't control the document and think it may be malformed:

```
var div = document.getElementById('xyz');
while (div) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    div = document.getElementById('xyz');
}
```

(Alternatives below.)

But you only need the loop with invalid HTML documents; if you control the document, there's no need, simply ensure the document is valid. `id` values **must** be unique. And yet, one sees plenty of documents where they aren't.

#### Adding:

```
var msgContainer = document.createElement('div');
msgContainer.id = 'xyz';             // No setAttribute required
msgContainer.className = 'someClass' // No setAttribute required, note it's "className" to avoid conflict with JavaScript reserved word
msgContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
document.body.appendChild(msgContainer);
```

---

If you don't like the code duplication in my loop above and you think you need the loop, you could do:

```
var div;
while (!!(div = document.getElementById('xyz'))) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

or

```
var div;
while (div = document.getElementById('xyz')) {
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

...although that last may well generate lint warnings from various tools, since it *looks* like you have `=` where you mean `==` or `===` (but in this case, we really do mean `=`).

Comment: thanks: what if there are multipe divs  with id = xyz.Will the remove  code u described remove all divs with id = xyz

Comment: @jslearner: Amusingly, I was just adding a note about that. :-)

Comment: @jslearner it does not make much sense to give same id to different div objects. id is the property used for getting each object. If you give them same id, how will you get each of them seperately ? Try creating a div containing those divs and give that div the id.